# javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No active transaction for PuId=

Tags: java, jpa, web-applications, websphere-8

i have web application. 
fetch from table working well

but
when I'm trying to update the same table, by using JPA i got exception message:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No active transaction for PuId =....
```

i am using transaction-type="JTA"(container manage) and transaction.required.
it seemed that

**

> I have an example of an update from MDB using JTA transaction type and there it's works well

**

**this is my persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="sysAdmin" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>
        org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>
    <jta-data-source>comp/env/jdbc/sys-SRV</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.sysAdminAppl</class>
    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.sysAdminTable</class>
    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.sysAdminTablePK</class>
    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.Dbsys0001</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="sqlserver" />
        <property name="Multithreaded" value="true" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="dbsys" />
        <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
        <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
<persistence-unit name="mtmAdminUpdate" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    </provider>

    <non-jta-data-source>comp/env/jdbc/jpa</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.sysAdminAppl</class>
    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.sysAdminTable</class>
    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.sysAdminTablePK</class>
    <class>com.sys.admin.jpa.dbsys0001</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="sqlserver" />
        <property name="Multithreaded" value="true" />
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.Schema" value="dbsys" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

**my servlet**

```
  package com.sys.admin.servlet;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.StringWriter;
  import java.io.Writer;
  import java.util.Enumeration;

  import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
  import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
  import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
  import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
  import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
  import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
  import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  import com.sys.admin.CRUD.MatamAppl;
  import com.sys.admin.jqgridPage.PageApplDetail;

  import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

 /**
 * Servlet implementation class ViewAppl
 */
 @WebServlet("/ViewAppl")
 @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
 public class ViewAppl extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION, unitName     = "sysAdmin")
    public EntityManager emJPA = null;
```

.
.
.
.

**the controller**

```
package com.sys.admin.jpa.controller;

import java.util.List;

import com.ibm.jpa.web.JPAManager;

import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ThrowsPattern;

import com.ibm.jpa.web.NamedQueryTarget;
import com.ibm.jpa.web.Action;
import com.sys.admin.jpa.SysAdminAppl;
import com.sys.admin.jpa.SysAdminApplPK;
import com.sys.admin.jpa.SysAdminTable;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@JPAManager(targetEntity = com.sys.admin.jpa.SysAdminAppl.class)
public class SysAdminApplManager {



    private EntityManager em;
    private String exceptionMessage;
.
.
.
.
@Action(Action.ACTION_TYPE.UPDATE)
    public String updateSysAdminAppl(SysAdminAppl sysAdminAppl)
            throws Exception {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            //em.getTransaction().begin();
            sysAdminAppl = em.merge(sysAdminAppl);
            //em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            exceptionMessage = ex.getMessage();
            try {
                if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                    em.getTransaction().rollback();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
                throw e;
            }
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return "";
    }
.
.
.
```

**this is my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>sysAdmin</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-ref  id="adminDb">
        <description></description>
        <res-ref-name>aliasDataSource</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>


</web-app>
```

.

**ibm-web-ext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-ext
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-ext_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1">

    <reload-interval value="3"/><resource-ref name="resourceSqlserver" isolation-level="TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED" connection-management-policy="DEFAULT"/>
    <enable-directory-browsing value="false"/>
    <enable-file-serving value="true"/>
    <enable-reloading value="true"/>
    <enable-serving-servlets-by-class-name value="true" />

</web-ext>
```

**ibm-web-bnd.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-bnd 
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-web-bnd_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.1">

    <virtual-host name="default_host" />

    <resource-ref name="aliasDataSource"
        binding-name="comp/env/jdbc/SYS-SRV">
    </resource-ref>

</web-bnd>
```

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, CMP transactions are set by EJBs, not Servlets in the J2EE6 spec.

I have had similar problems in the past which were related to my misunderstanding of this point.

If you look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html, the documentation
lays this out pretty clearly:

> In an enterprise bean with container-managed transaction demarcation,
>   the EJB container sets the boundaries of the transactions. You can use
>   container-managed transactions with any type of enterprise bean:
>   session or message-driven. Container-managed transactions simplify
>   development because the enterprise bean code does not explicitly mark
>   the transaction’s boundaries. The code does not include statements
>   that begin and end the transaction. By default, if no transaction
>   demarcation is specified, enterprise beans use container-managed
>   transaction demarcation.
>
> Typically, the container begins a transaction immediately before an
>   enterprise bean method starts and commits the transaction just before
>   the method exits. Each method can be associated with a single
>   transaction. Nested or multiple transactions are not allowed within a
>   method.

In other words... break out your persistence code into an EJB, and call that from your servlet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a JTA transaction before invoking JPA: use `@Resource UserTransaction userTran`, and then use `userTran.begin()`/`userTran.commit()` around the calls to JPA.